# Can I see nhibernate automapper mappings

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Automapping in Nhibernate has been this wonderful magical thing, but now something strange is happening and I want to peel back this magical layer and see the actual mappings that are getting generated.

Is there a way to see the mappings generated by automapper and my overrides so I can see if it's doing what I think it's doing?

Comment: IIRC You can write out the hbm mapping files that NH generates - then you can inspect them to find out what it is actually using, let me dig up a code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Fluent then you should be able to write the persistence model to the disk:

```
// In your fluent config code
// assuming config is of type FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration
var model = new FluentNHibernate.PersistenceModel();

config.Mappings(m => m.UsePersistenceModel(model));

model.WriteMappingsTo(@"C:\some_folder_name_for_hbm_files_to_go_into");
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Tiny correction - WriteMappings parameter is a folder to write all the mapping files to.

Comment: Ah yes, good point! (I did wonder why I'd put `c:\somefoldername` in my code and not a file name!)